# Looping through two string arrays and setting them as object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I need to loop through two arrays of strings and set those as object properties.  Both arrays are the same length.

I've tried looping through one array but can't find anything about looping through two arrays at once and setting them as properties in an object.

Example:

```
var propertyName = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var propertyValue = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var = {};
```

Result to be expected:

```
obj = [
   {propertyName: "a", propertyValue: "1"},
   {propertyName: "b", propertyValue: "2"},
   {propertyName: "c", propertyValue: "3"},
   {propertyName: "d", propertyValue: "4"},
];
```

(Update for what I have tried)
This is what I have tried so far but couldn't figure out how to get to the second array.  Thanks to everyone who answered so quickly.

```
for (var in propertyName) {
    obj.propertyName = propertyName[i].toString();
    System.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Share the code you have so far looping through one. It will be helpful to see the code you have tried, then help you get the results you desire.

Comment: How are these arrays populated in the first place?when you want to store them as a single object(key,value pairs) i dont see why you have to store them in two seperate arrays.I would suggest you to start from where these arrays are getting populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```js
let propertyName = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let propertyValue = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

let obj = propertyName.map((name, index) => ({propertyName: name, propertyValue: propertyValue[index]}))
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map and build a object with desired values

```js
var propertyName = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var propertyValue = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

let op = propertyName.map((e,i)=> ({
  propertyName: e,
  propertyValue: propertyValue[i]
}))

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know for sure that each array's index match with the other array's index in their defined order then you can just use them in the same loop like this...

```
var obj = [];    

for(var i = 0; i < propertyName.length; i++) {
    obj.push({
        propertyName: propertyName[i], 
        propertyValue: propertyValue[i]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You coudl take [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and map all value to the same index object.

This works for an arbitrary count of properties, as long as the length of the array is the same.

```js
var propertyName = ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    propertyValue = ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    result = Object
        .entries({ propertyName, propertyValue })
        .reduce((r, [k, a]) => a.map((v, i) => Object.assign(r[i] || {}, { [k]: v })), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```